# How to save a tensorflow dataset to multiple shards without using enumerate

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow dataset with some elements in it, and I want to save it with `tf.data.Dataset.save` such that each element gets its own shard. Thus if the dataset contains 2,000 elements, it would be saved to 2,000 shards.

The documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=nightly#save) specifies how to create 1 shard only, but not how to make a shard for each element.

Below, I am able to do it with enumerate, but is there another way to do it without also saving the index from `enumerate`?

```
tuple_data = np.array([3, 4])
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tuple_data)
data = data.enumerate()
print(list(data.as_numpy_iterator()))
# [(0, 3), (1, 4)]

data.save(path='~/Desktop/1', shard_func=lambda i, x: i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not useful for your question, but if someone just wants to create shards, lets mention that it is possible to use random:

```
tf.data.experimental.save(trainingdata, "./tmpTrainingData",
                          shard_func=lambda x, y:  np.int64(random.randint(0,99)) )
```

Now I wonder if your goal could be obtained by calling hash and producing a int64. Even if it can, I guess there is some risk of collision.